# What is the time complexity of this dfs algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

**Problem Statement**: Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array. // A leetcode problem

I was just confused about calculating the complexities of it. What is the tike complexity and could you please recommend any books or tutorial that teaches calculation of tie complexity

```
   class Solution {
    public boolean canJump(int[] nums,int sum,boolean isreach[]) {
        if(sum == nums.length-1){
            return true;
        }
        if(sum >= nums.length){
            return false;
        }
        if(isreach[sum]) return true;
        int j = nums[sum];
        int k = 1;
        boolean check = false;
        while( k <= j && sum + k < nums.length ){       
           check = check || canJump(nums, sum+k,isreach);
           if(check) {isreach[sum] = check; return true;}
           k++;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean canJump(int[] nums) {
        boolean isreach[] = new boolean[nums.length];
        return canJump(nums,0,isreach);
    }
 }
```

In my opinion, it is n^2

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ suppose the array is **[3,3,3,3]**, so the total number of calls made will be 3+2+1+0 = 6 which is n*(n-1)/2 so its n^2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a breadth-first search algorithm. I'm pretty sure the question you're referring to is the [Jump Game problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/), whose optimal solution is to use Dynamic Programming, not breadth-first search.

The algorithm you've presented above is simply a top-down dynamic programming algorithm that memoizes the solutions to smaller subproblems that it finds. The runtime of this algorithm is `O(N)` (where `N` is the `sum` value you want to reach) since there are at most `N` distinct states that you will visit.

Comment: I already knew the optimal solution and it's indeed dfs you start from first array element then will it call to next possible till u reach the end and then backtrack